# umbraco site Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: mysql, database, umbraco, umbraco6

please help my umbraco site when i try to login to backend comes up Server Error in '/' Application i attached a screen grab below.

[image: Server Error in '/' Application]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to a conflict with something in your binary folder.  All the searching I did on this error revealed a common link to a conflict with certain versions of Umbraco VS Contour.

The most common suggestion is to rename the Umbraco.Forms.Core.Providers.V7.dll file in your bin directory.

If this works, you need to look into which version of Contour you should be using for the version of Umbraco you have to see if there is a conflict there.

If that doesn't work, you might want to look at whichever packages you've installed lately and start removing their DLLs.

Worse comes to worse, rename your bin folder, bring in a fresh one for the version of Umbraco you're using, and then bring the DLLs from your renamed bin folder until you can narrow down which one it is that's causing your grief.

I hope that helps!